# Installing PostGIS behind firewall on server with no Internet connection?

Tags: postgis, installation

I'm trying to install PostGIS on a server so that I can run some SQL scripts for styling in QGIS, but to do so it seems to have to install through Stack Builder which requires an Internet connection.

I have installed PostgreSQL, so how do I install the PostGIS plugin locally?

Comment: You can copy the installer from another computer

Comment: what operating system are you running this on?